# How to keep checkbox checked and content shown when reload page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have this html content:

```
<div class="myClass" style="display:none">
<table class="table table-hover">
.....
</table>
</div>
```

As you can see this is a table which is **hidden**

I have a `checkbox` to show this if the checkbox is checked

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="test" onclick="toggle('.myClass', this)" autocomplete="on" ></legend>
    <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(className, obj) {
    var $input = $(obj);
    if ($input.prop('checked')) $(className).show(1000);
    else $(className).hide(1000);
}
</script>
```

As you can see if checkbox is checked it will be shown and if it's unchecked it will hide my `div`

everything works great.

Now if I reload this page I want to keep the checked checkbox if it was checked or if it was unchecked I got it this way:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
    $('input').prop('checked', test || false);
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(className).show(1000); //checked
        }
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
</script>
```

**Now my problem is**

when I reload the page if the checkbox is checked it's not showing the content.... so I have to uncheck it and check it again to make it work.

Is there a possible way to reload the page and keep my content shown if the checkbox is checked?

**EDIT**

thanks to @nnnnnn as answered before I got this working :

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="test" ></legend>
    <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

<div class="myClass" style="display:none">
<table class="table table-hover">
...
</table>

<script>
$(function(){        
    $('#test')
      .prop('checked', localStorage.input === 'true')
      .on('click', function() {
         localStorage.input = this.checked;
         if (this.checked) {
           $('.myClass').show(1000); //checked
         } else {
           $('.myClass').hide(1000);
         }
      })
      .trigger('change');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically setting an element's `checked` property does *not* trigger any `click` or `change` handlers attached to the element. So after the line where you set that, you need to explicitly trigger the `change` handler yourself by calling `.trigger('change')`, or just `.change()`.

You can consolidate your code by selecting `$('#test')` once and then chaining the required methods after it:

```
<script>
$(function(){        
    $('#test')
      .prop('checked', localStorage.input === 'true')
      .on('change', function() {
         localStorage.input = this.checked;
         if (this.checked) {
           $('.myClass').show(1000); //checked
         } else {
           $('.myClass').hide(1000);
         }
      })
      .trigger('change');
});
</script>
```

You shouldn't need the `toggle()` function or the inline `onclick` handler in addition to binding the event handler through jQuery.

Note that I've further simplified things. `var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;` can be simplified to `var test = localStorage.input === 'true';`, because the `===` operator returns a boolean, and on the next line the `|| false` can be removed because at that point you know that `test` is a boolean. And beyond that, you don't really need the `test` variable at all given that you only use it once after it is set.

Also, you were a bit inconsistent with how you test the `checked` state, using `$(this).is(':checked')` in one place and `$(this).prop('checked')` on the next line. Both work, but given that `this` is a reference to the DOM element, you can simply say `this.checked` to test the property directly without jQuery. (The only time `.is(':checked')` makes sense is when called on a jQuery object that contains multiple elements, and you want to see if at least one of them is checked.)

Comment: Hey! thank you very much for your answer, after trying your code if I have it checked I reload page and it changes to unchecked, if I reload page again it changes to checked and shown the content as I expected but what I really need is if I have it checked I and page needs to be reloaded it has to be checked and show my content. I just edited my question where I added your code!

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's because the `.trigger('click')` changes the checked status the same as if a user clicked the box. That wouldn't have happened if using the `'change'` event, sorry. I'll update my answer to just use `'change'` - I think probably my recommendation for using `'click'` instead is outdated now anyway (it only really applied for older IE when "clicking" the box via the keyboard, so...).

Comment: So that worked? By the way, there's no need to edit questions to add code from answers, especially if you don't include an explanation that there is still a problem with the code just added, so if my edit fixed the issue it might be best to remove that from your question again.

Comment: Yeah that worked, oh sorry for that, I was just to let you know the changes I've made but that's absolutely working as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding code line  $('input').change(); as

```
 $(function(){
        var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
        $('input').prop('checked', test || false);
         $('input').change();
    });
```